# onDelete('cascade') has no effect Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.6

*Laravel 5.6 
mysql 14.14*

I'm trying to use **OnDelete('cascade')** but it has no effect! - When I delete a **post**, the corresponding **photo** must be deleted. But the cascade doesn't work. (The post is deleted but the photo entry on the database is not deleted and I get no error)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('photo_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('photo_id')->references('id')->on('photos')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}


class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'photo_id',
    ];

    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
}

class Photo extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
    }
}

mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------    -------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                            | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------    -------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking,     and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |


mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;
| posts | CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`photo_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `posts_photo_id_index` (`photo_id`),
CONSTRAINT `posts_photo_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`photo_id`) REFERENCES   `photos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4     COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: Open up phpmyadmin or sequel pro and open the table and open the trigger tab and see yourself whats in there.

Comment: I'm using Homestead. I only have access to mysql command line via 'vagrant ssh'. What is its mysql command?

Comment: Check the foreign key constraint on the `posts` table using `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;` on MySQL CLI, it is possible that you don't have proper foreign key constraints because your storage engine is not INNOBD.

Comment: `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE 'Table' = 'posts';`

Comment: `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE 'Table' = 'posts';` gives me `Empty set`. I updated the question. As you can see, my default engine is 'InnoDB'. In addition, when I run `show table status where name='posts';` and `show table status where name='photos';`, the engine is set to 'InnoDB'.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi I edited the question to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your relationship structure, when you will delete a `photo` this will cascade down to the `posts` table so see if a foreign contraint failed, as it turns out yes, there is a post that refrences this photo, then that post will be deleted as well.

Consider this,

```
posts:
- id
- title
- body

photos:
- id
- path
- post_id - references id on posts with onDelete('cascade')
```

With this structure you can have photo to be deleted if a post is deleted.

Or, if you dont want to change the structure. You can consider deleting related photos on your laravel side, you can use `deleting` model event, to manually delete the related photos. This helps making sure that whenever a post is being deleted its related photo is deleted.

Comment: Considering a real-life-like context, which structure is correct? (because both work fine (except this issue that I have) )

Comment: Both are one to many relationships but inverse of each other. 
According to your structure, a post can have only one photo, but a photo may belong to more than one post.

According to the one I suggested, A post can have many photos, but a photo belongs to a single post

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation to this problem is that your foreign key constraint does not exist, despite the fact that you said there must be one in the migration file. It comes from the fact that the storage engine is not set to INNODB.

But I see that you wrote `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` in your migration, so I assume it would work. But you can check that your storage engine is INNOBD by typing this command:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

If you see that INNODB is not your default engine, type this in your MySQL CLI:

```
SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine=INNODB
```

Then rerun your migrations and the cascade delete should work.

Comment: I updated my question. The default is InnoDB and when I run `show table status where name='posts';` and `show table status where name='photos';` the engine is InnoDB